# How can I group consecutive time periods together in python?

Tags: python, python-itertools

If I have sorted list of time periods like p1, p2, p3, each with start and end times; how can I group them together if they're consecutive, e.g. p2 starting when p1 ends, but p3 starting at some later time would result in the following grouping: [p1,p2], [p3], ...?

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that we cannot directly compare item to the last item in `groupby()`, so first we need to set group index attribute on each item while looping over the list of items; then `groupby()` can use these attributes to create groups:

```
import itertools
last = None
n = 1    
for period in periods:
  if last and period.start != period.end:
    n+=1
  period.n = n
  last = period
groups = itertools.groupby(periods, lambda p: p.n)
# if total num of items isn't too big, for easier debugging or logging,
# convert each subgroup iterator to a list:
groups = (list(g[1]) for g in groups)
```